# save jquery value with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have form like this

```
<div id="signUp" class="form-inline">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="">I Sign up as</label>
      <input id="placehold" type="text" class="form-control text-center" readonly/>
      <div class="smallspace"></div>
      <div class="displayTable">
         <div class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" class="radio_item" value="Company"  name="item" id="radioCompany">
            <label class="label_item" for="radioCompany"></label>
            <p class="text-center colorGrey">Company</p>
         </div>
         <div class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" class="radio_item" value="Chef"  name="item" id="radioChef">
            <label class="label_item" for="radioChef"></label>
            <p class="text-center colorGrey">Chef</p>
         </div>
         <div class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" class="radio_item" value="Food lover" name="item" id="radioFoodLover">
            <label class="label_item" for="radioFoodLover"></label>
            <p class="text-center colorGrey">Food lover</p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<script src="js/upload.js"></script>
```

inside upload js i code like this

```
(function($) {
    "use strict";

    // register
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#signUp input').on('change', function() {
            var signUp = $(this).val();
            $("#placehold").val(signUp);//show value of chosen radio button to input text
        });
    });

})(jQuery);
```

summary this code is, i have input text(readonly) and 2 radio button, when we choose the radio button then system will get the value of the choosen than show it to the input type text.

the reason i put the validation to other file because honestly it got so much validation, for another input too. i just didnt like it if i have to place the validation inside html file.

my question is: is it posible to get that value and store it to database via PHP?

Comment: use ajax in this case

Comment: can you show me what your layout look like?

Comment: i put it in jsfiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0rcxgup6/ here sir

Comment: now you want to save textbox field value in database?

Answer (score 0):

You should use ajax for this task your code will be looking like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#signUp input').on('change', function() {
            var signUp = $(this).val();
            $("#placehold").val(signUp);//show value of chosen radio button to input text
            //php file that have database codes
            $.post("test.php",{
              signup: signUp, //send signUp js variable to $_POST['signup'] 
            },
           function(data,status){
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status); //callback event that fires when the post request successfully sent (removable)
            });
        });
});
```

**test.php** file contains..

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['signup'])){
    // your database code
   echo $_POST['signup']; //replace it with your code
 }

?>
```